# How to set dates in x axis with non-uniform interval?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to draw a time-plot using the `matplotlib.dates` module. From the tutorial, I know how to set regular interval date like the following:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(DayLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%Y-%m"))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_...
```

However, in my data there are some months missing. My xaxis date is more like : Jan, Feb, May, Jul, Sep, Oct, Sep... no pattern is formed...

How can I deal with such situation?.

Comment: Do you want to create a scatter plot, x-axis having month and y axis being values?

Comment: yes...But the plot is line-plot more likely...

Comment: how are you data for x axis then?  cant you just like create array for time, array for value, and feed like `plot(times, values)`, like that?  sorry if not i am not getting your point...

Comment: Yes, it is also a good solution...But how can I set the x axix into  date format? I mean I want the x axis appears like 2009-08, 2010-10 this kind of thing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I use ticker to manually set the xaxis.setMajorFormatter(FixedFormatter(dateStr)) into the date format I want. And I use xaxis.set_major_locator(IndexLocator(1, 0)) to set the location of the date str... However, do you have a more decent way to do the same thing?

Comment: I start to see how ugly this is...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216273/irregular-matplotlib-date-x-axis-labels  Hope somebody knows something more reasonable.

Comment: also, apology if i sounded pretentious, i thought you are dealing with something simple.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you may need to use

```
matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator
```

Example which puts labels at data points 1, 10 and the last one:

```
import pylab as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

# dates (unequally spaced, but works exactly same for equally spaced dates too)
dates = plt.date2num(datetime(2010,3,1))  + np.array([0, 10, 50, 100, 180, 300])
# just some data
data = dates**2
plt.plot_date(dates,data)

ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(dates[[1, 3, len(dates)-1]]))
# for some reason this is needed to get the month displayed too
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%Y-%m"))
plt.show()
```

Comment: This does change label format.  The only thing I needed was  `from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter`

Comment: Hmm, AnneS's question is a bit unclear.  But just using `plot_date` will  put equally spaced ticks and labels on the plot even for unequally spaced data.  So, I figured that the question was 'How to set dates _labels_ in x axis with ununiform interval', which above answers.

Comment: @yosukesabai Well, as stated in above comment, I don't think `DateFormatter` is actually needed so I removed it from the code.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Mauro's solution, i tried to plot data pair where dates are irregularly spaced, so that i can find this QA sometime in future.

```
import pylab as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

# dates, irregularly spaced
y = 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011
m =    9,   11,   12,    3,    4


dates = np.array([plt.date2num(datetime(yy,mm,1)) for yy,mm in zip(y,m)])
print dates


# just some data
data = dates**2
print data


plt.plot_date(dates,data)

ax = plt.gca()
# need some more thnking for properly locate which date to label
#ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(dates[[1, 10, len(dates)-1]]))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%Y-%m"))
plt.show()
```

[image]